# Print Jasper Report without pages

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm creating HTML (popup window), EXCEL and PDF report and would like to show my reports on one page. This report is not going to be used for printing, so there is no need separate my report into pages. Plus later users would like to use Buildin Excel sorting.

Is there an option to ignore pages?

Comment: I can't recall how does the page distinction in the HTML output look like. Could you describe it?

Comment: It adds two <br/>'s at the end of the page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Under the Report Properties in the "More . . ." section.  There is a Ignore Pagination option.  Check this box and it should work

Answer (score 22):

Toggle [pagination](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRParameter.html#IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION) during report filling. For example, Excel or HTML output should not be paginated. Sample code:

```
parameters.put(JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, true);
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, data);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there an option to ignore pages, but you can change the page height to a very big number (10000)?

In the XML, set the pageHeight attribute to "10000", or similar.

Comment: hardcode height does not looks suitable when Jasper define a property for that.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to checking "Ignore pagination", you should be able to get a similar effect by setting the page bands' height to zero. At least for Excel and HTML reports, not sure about PDF.

This is helpful for large reports when you want to use [Jasper's Virtualizer feature](http://thoughtstoblog.blogspot.com/2008/08/generating-huge-reports-in.html). The reason is that the virtualizer stores entire pages on disk, and if you enable ignore pagination, you will not get the benefit from the virtualizer and risk running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

My project is using net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport ver 3.6.1 to generate csv file and surprisingly I see the csv output file is inserted with alternate ,,1,,, and ,,9,,, at every 42nd line.

Refer here: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/nopagebreak/

I added the following setting in the jrxml template

```
<jasperReport ... isIgnorePagination="true" ...> 
... 
</jasperReport>
```

and the empty line is gone.